# $KK$-groups definitions

Tags: operator-theory, definition, operator-algebras, k-theory

In [$K$ Theory of Operator Algebras, page 144](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/bruceb/Book6.pdf) and a [paper by Skandalis, page 35](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/dept/conf/ncgoa08/talks/skandalis2.pdf)  the $KK$ groups are defined differently:

Both are triples $(E,\phi, F)$ but Skandalis does not require the condition that

$$\pi(a)(F-F^*) \in \mathcal{K}(E)$$

Are the definitions different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they are equivalent, as given in a paper [by Kasparov and Skandalis.](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.skandalis/Publications/Publi21.pdf)